# Why does acts-as-taggable-on upgrade rails gem from 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a rails app that uses rails gem v3.1.1 and acts-as-taggable-on gem v2.1.1.

Our server build installs the rails v3.1.1 gem before the acts-as-taggable-on v2.1.1 gem.

My problem is that installing the acts-as-taggable-on gem also installs the latest rails (3.2.1) even though I already have rails installed and I end up with 2 versions of rails installed.

Looking at the [acts-as-taggable-on gemspec](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/acts-as-taggable-on.gemspec) it has rails as a dependency. On install, I would expect acts-as-taggable on to know that the rails gem is installed and not install the latest version.

Can you explain why it installs rails again, and if there is a way to stop it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you installing your gems?

Comment: Hi Frederick, I use gem install (rather than bundler) and specify the version as I create an Amazon EC2 machine image with all our app dependencies but not our app code (which I believe is best practice). Using bundler would require our app to be deployed as part of the server build - I think the two should be independent.

Comment: This is exactly the problem bundler was designed to solve. You could still use bundler by just copying your Gemfile & Gemfile.lock to the server when you build your image. Personally when I build EC2 images i don't put gems in there as they seem to change often enough to make it a hassle

Comment: Thanks Frederick, I'll try using just the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock - thinking about it, it makes more sense managing the versions in one place rather than the Gemfile & the server build scripts. I just hope that the acts_as_taggable_on gem doesn't install the latest rails gem when it is installed by bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.2.2 of the gem bumps the Rails dependency down to 3.x instead of 3.2.  If you're able to upgrade acts-as-taggable-on, switch to v2.2.2 and you should no longer have a dependency clash.

Comment: Actually, looking back at this, the gem dependency was never higher than 3.1.  As Frederick Cheung suggested, the problem may be that you're using the wrong method for managing your gems.  Are you using **Bundler** to do the installs?  When working with Rails, you should be putting your dependencies in your **Gemfile** and running `bundle install` to automate your gem installation.  Don't install gems with `gem install`.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't looked at upgrading to 2.2.2. I expect I can but also suspect that the same thing will happen - as you say, the dependency was never higher than 3.1.